# python dictionary values sorting

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries, `dict1` and `dict2` which contain the same keys, but different values for the keys.  What I want to do is for each dictionary, sort the values from largest to smallest, and then give each value a rank 1-N, 1 being the largest value.  From here, I want to get the difference of the ranks for the values in each dictionary for the same key. For example:

```
dict1 = {a:0.6, b:0.3, c:0.9, d:1.2, e:0.2}
dict2 = {a:1.4, b:7.7, c:9.0, d:2.5, e:2.0}

# sorting by values would look like this:
dict1 = {d:1.2, c:0.9, a:0.6, b:0.3, e:0.2}
dict2 = {c:9.0, b:7.7, d:2.5, e:2.0, a:1.4}

#ranking the values would produce this:
dict1 = {d:1, c:2, a:3, b:4, e:5}
dict2 = {c:1, b:2, d:3, e:4, a:5}

#computing the difference between ranks would be something like this:
diffs = {}
for x in dict1.keys():
    diffs[x] = (dict1[x] - dict2[x])

#diffs would look like this:
diffs[a] = -2
diffs[b] = 2
diffs[c] = 1
diffs[d] = -2
diffs[e] = 1
```

I know dictionaries are meant to be random and not sortable, but maybe there is a method to put the keys and values into a list?  The main challenges I am facing are getting the keys and values sorted by value (largest to smallest) and then changing the value to its respective rank in the sorted list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple solution for small dicts is

```
dict1 = {"a":0.6, "b":0.3, "c":0.9, "d":1.2, "e":0.2}
dict2 = {"a":1.4, "b":7.7, "c":9.0, "d":2.5, "e":2.0}
k1 = sorted(dict1, key=dict1.get)
k2 = sorted(dict2, key=dict2.get)
diffs = dict((k, k2.index(k) - k1.index(k)) for k in dict1)
```

A more efficient, less readable version for larger dicts:

```
ranks1 = dict(map(reversed, enumerate(sorted(dict1, key=dict1.get))))
ranks2 = dict(map(reversed, enumerate(sorted(dict2, key=dict2.get))))
diffs = dict((k, ranks2[k] - ranks1[k]) for k in dict1)
```

Comment: +1. Not many people use `map` and `reversed` this way. Tricky :-) But I'd suggest to use `itertools.imap` to spare some memory.

Comment: Agreed.  Typically I recommend list comprehensions or generator expressions over map (wasn't aware of imap until now) for performance reasons, but I think this is a better, more readable solution.  Kudos :-)

Comment: Wouldn't `sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])` be faster, since then you don't need to look up every value in the dictionary?

Comment: @Aleksi: First, dictionary lookup is quite fast.  I think `sorted(dict1, key=dict1.get)` is faster since you don't have the overhead of calling a Python function for each item.  Of course your expression can be written as `sorted(dict1.items(), key=operator.itermgetter(1))`, eliminating the lambda function and invalidating this argument.  But second, Your expression returns a different list than mine.  I'd need to get rid of the values somehow.

Comment: @Sven: Yes, I was thinking something in the lines of `dict((key, rank) for rank, (key, value) in enumerate(sorted(dict1.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))))`, but in case the list comprehension is slower than `map`+`reversed`, my point is indeed moot.

Comment: @Sven: I just timed it; `dict((key, rank) for rank, (key, value) in enumerate(sorted(dict1.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))))` is twice as fast as `dict(map(reversed, enumerate(sorted(dict1, key=dict1.get))))` at least for dictionaries of size 10, 100 and 1000.

Comment: @Sven, I did not try the code until now, but the ranking system seams to not be working correctly.  I have a rather large data set (over 1000 entries in each dict) and I used the code you put for large dicts.  how does the code handle it when there is more than one instance of the same value? Maybe the sorting is off? because there are entries that I know should be ranked high (>15) and ranked in the 1000's.

Comment: @marsx: I did the ranking in reverse order.  I figured you were only interested in the `diffs`, not in the ranks itself, so I used the reverse ranking, simply resulting in `diffs` having the opposite sign -- that's why I used `ranks2[k] - ranks1[k]` where you have `dict1[x] - dict2[x]`.  If you want to have the ranking the way you specified, simply add `reverse=True` to the `sorted()` calls and switch the sign of `diffs` again.

Answer (score 6):

You may be interested in [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Here's a sample, my initial thougth is you were also looking for dictionaries with keys ordered by values, things that `od1` and `od2` are.

```
d1 = {"a":0.6, "b":0.3, "c":0.9, "d":1.2, "e":0.2}
d2 = {"a":1.4, "b":7.7, "c":9.0, "d":2.5, "e":2.0}

od1 = OrderedDict(sorted(d1.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
od2 = OrderedDict(sorted(d2.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))

k1 = od1.keys()
k2 = od2.keys()

diff = dict((k, n - k2.index(k)) for n, k in enumerate(k1))
```

If you don't need them then Sven solution is probably faster.

**edit**: not that faster honestly... (sven.py is his second, more efficient version):

```
$ cat /tmp/mine.py | time python -m timeit
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0842 usec per loop
real    0m 3.69s
user    0m 3.38s
sys 0m 0.03s
$ cat /tmp/sven.py | time python -m timeit
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.085 usec per loop
real    0m 3.86s
user    0m 3.42s
sys 0m 0.03s
```

If someone wants to post formatted bigger dicts I'll test them too.

Comment: This is the wrong tool for the job, the asker does not really need an ordered dictionary, he just needs a way to rank the values.

Comment: Asker says: _The main challenges I am facing are getting the keys and values sorted by value_ and `OrderedDict` seems to me the right tool

Comment: I can't see how an `OrderedDict` simplifies the task of generating the `diffs` dictionary.  Could you give a full example?  (BTW, not my downvote.)

Comment: Yes, but look at the problem. First you have dictionaries, then you need to get the ranking of the values (for which you do not need ordered dictionaries), and then you want the ranking results in the final dictionary. You don't *need* ordered dictionaries anywhere, they are the wrong tool for the job. Look at Svens answer, for example.

Answer (score 2):

What version of python are you using?  If 2.7, use OrderedDict.

Per the Python 2.7 [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html):

```
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=d.get))
```

If you're using Python 2.4-2.6 you can still use OrderedDict by installing it from pypi [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordereddict) or if you have [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads), run

```
easy_install ordereddict
```

Comment: Agreed!  Especially since both of our answers are perfectly valid solutions.  I upvoted yours as well to negate the actions of whoever did it.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I don't think an `OrderedDict` is of any help here.  To achieve what the OP wants, you don't need to actually sort the dictionaries.  Moreover, the key function you gave is wrong.

Comment: Oh damn, you're right about the key function.  I just copied/pasted straight from the docs... Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is not the right data structure to solve this problem. You should convert to sorted lists as soon as possible and produce the dictionary only as the final result. The following sample solution uses iterators and generator expressions where possible, to avoid creating too many (potentially large) helper lists along the way:

```
def get_ranking(vals):
    '''Return a list of pairs: (key, ranking), sorted by key.'''
    ranking = sorted(((v, k) for k, v in vals.iteritems()), reverse=True)
    return sorted((k, i) for (i, (_v, k)) in enumerate(ranking))

def ranking_diff(rank1, rank2):
    return dict((k, v1 - v2) for (k, v1), (_, v2) in itertools.izip(rank1, rank2))

def get_diffs(dict1, dict2):
    r1 = get_ranking(dict1)
    r2 = get_ranking(dict2)
    return ranking_diff(r1, r2)

print get_diffs(dict1, dict2)
# prints: {'a': -2, 'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'e': 1, 'd': -2}
```

Please note that this solution assumes that both dicts contain exactly the same keys.