# python ranking a list of values, using average rank for non-unique values

Tags: python

Is there a more pythonic, faster want to rank a dictionary by values and average the rank for the non unique values. My approach:

```
d = {'a':5,'b':5,'c':5,'d':1,'e':6}
ordered_keys = sorted(d, key=d.get)
ordered_v = [d[k] for k in ordered_keys]
value_rank = [(ordered_v.index(v)+1)+(ordered_v.count(v)-1)/2 for v in ordered_v]
ranked_key_list = zip(ordered_keys,value_rank)
[('d', 1), ('a', 3), ('c', 3), ('b', 3), ('e', 5)]
```

This broad discussion on sorting dictionaries was very helpful: [python dictionary values sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046049/python-dictionary-values-sorting)

Comment: @the_wolf thanks for point that out. I don't in my code. I was trying to make things clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the bottleneck of your algorithmn is the fact that .index and .count are O(n), therefore your bottle neck is this line:

```
value_rank = [(ordered_v.index(v)+1)+(ordered_v.count(v)-1)/2 for v in ordered_v]
```

causing your overall performance to be  O(n^2)

I have made a O(n*log(n)) algorithm for you (the bottle neck is now the sorting):

```
import collections

d = {'a':5,'b':5,'c':5,'d':1,'e':6}
my_d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key, val in d.items():
    my_d[val].append(key)

ranked_key_list = [] 
n = v = 1
for _, my_list in sorted(my_d.items()):
    v = n + (len(my_list)-1)/2 
    for e in my_list:
        n += 1
        ranked_key_list.append((e, v))
```

Comment: What's the n in your O(n)? Surely it can't be the number of items in the dict, as `sorted()` is O(n*lg(n)).

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks azorius!

Comment: @Cole as you can see from lqc, I lied the line is now O(n) instead of O(n^2) but the algorithm overall is still O(nlog(n)) because of the sorting

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually needed exactly that solution for my problem.

Comment: I just have one addition: You need to change the division to 2. in order to get the real average rank if that's your goal.

Comment: interesting to see collections.defaultdict in use (:  This would be a little faster if you increment n by len(my_list) instead of for each e.

Answer (score 3):

What you have is pretty good, I doubt there is a solution that is much shorter.

As for efficiency, the repeated use of `list.index()` and `list.count()` might slow this down for large data sets.

Here is an alternative implementation that should be more efficient if you are doing this for a lot of data:

```
from itertools import groupby

d = {'a':5,'b':5,'c':5,'d':1,'e':6}
ranked_key_list = []
i = 1
for k, g in groupby(sorted(d.keys(), key=d.get), key=d.get):
    g = list(g)
    rank = i + (len(g)-1) / 2
    ranked_key_list.extend((k, rank) for k in g)
    i += len(g)
```

Comment: This is almost an identical algorithm to the accepted answer, but should be faster as it uses `groupby` to group the keys. If there are many repeated keys, this could be slower however (as it sorts the whole key list instead of just the sets of repeated keys).

Answer (score 0):

```
key_list = zip(dict.keys(), dict.values())
ranked_key_list = sorted(key_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

edit: just realized I didn't do the average value thing.... could you clarify a little more? how is the average of 3 5s = 3??

Comment: it's not the average it's the average rank, so the lowest = 1 and the highest = length, so 1 = 1, all the 5= 3 because the 5 are ranked 2 3 and 4 and (2+3+4)/3 = 3 - also: dict.items() is the same as your zip line

Comment: @cameron the ranking of the keys without averaging would be [('d',1),('a',2),('b',3),('c',4),('e',5)]. 'a','b','c' have the same values. Their average rank is the average of [2,3,4]