# sort dict by value python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.6

Assume that I have a dict.

```
data = {1:'b', 2:'a'}
```

And I want to sort data by 'b' and 'a' so I get the result

```
'a','b'
```

How do I do that?
Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python dictionary values sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046049/python-dictionary-values-sorting)

Comment: And what if I want a list of keys sorted by value? So the original would return [2, 1], could be a list of players sorted by their scores for example, discarding the scores.

Comment: @gseattle `sorted(data.keys(), key=data.get)`

Answer (score 183):

To get the values use

```
sorted(data.values())
```

To get the matching keys, use a `key` function

```
sorted(data, key=data.get)
```

To get a list of tuples ordered by value

```
sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Related: see the discussion here: [Dictionaries are ordered in Python 3.6+](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39980323/174728)

Comment: Ok, sorry. What I meant was to get (2:'a',1:'b')... any ideas?

Comment: @kingRauk, dict's are unordered, but you can make an ordered list of tuples

Comment: sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True) for reveresed order

Answer (score 48):

If you actually want to sort the dictionary instead of just obtaining a sorted list use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> data = {1: 'b', 2: 'a'}
>>> d = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))
>>> d
OrderedDict([(2, 'a'), (1, 'b')])
>>> d.values()
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: The sad thing is that is in Python 2.6.5... that does not support OrderedDict

Comment: @kingRauk then don't tag your question Python 2.7.... Also a lot of things you have mentioned in the comments should have been in your question to begin with

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that...

Comment: @kingRauk No problem at all, it's all good

Answer (score 18):

From your comment to gnibbler answer, i'd say you want a list of pairs of key-value sorted by value:

```
sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Answer (score 11):

Thanks for all answers.
You are all my heros ;-)

Did in the end something like this:

```
d = sorted(data, key = data.get)

for key in d:
    text = data[key]
```

Answer (score 9):

Sort the values:

```
sorted(data.values())
```

returns

```
['a','b']
```

Answer (score 6):

I also think it is important to note that Python `dict` object type is a hash table ([more on this here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2000-March/048085.html)), and thus is not capable of being sorted without converting its keys/values to lists. What this allows is `dict` item retrieval in constant time `O(1)`, no matter the size/number of elements in a dictionary.

Having said that, once you sort its keys - `sorted(data.keys())`, or values - `sorted(data.values())`, you can then use that list to access keys/values in design patterns such as these:

```
for sortedKey in sorted(dictionary):
    print dictionary[sortedKeY] # gives the values sorted by key

for sortedValue in sorted(dictionary.values()):
    print sortedValue # gives the values sorted by value
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `sorted(dictionary)` is better than `sorted(dictionary.keys())`

Comment: @jamylak thanks for the suggestion, but I wonder if it behaves in a different pattern then what `.keys()` would do?

Comment: It's semantically equivalent but faster and more idiomatic

Answer (score 5):

You could created sorted list from Values and rebuild the dictionary:

```
myDictionary={"two":"2", "one":"1", "five":"5", "1four":"4"}

newDictionary={}

sortedList=sorted(myDictionary.values())

for sortedKey in sortedList:
    for key, value in myDictionary.items():
        if value==sortedKey:
            newDictionary[key]=value
```

Output: newDictionary={'one': '1', 'two': '2', '1four': '4', 'five': '5'}

Answer (score 4):

In your comment in response to John, you suggest that you want the keys and values of the dictionary, not just the values.

[PEP 256](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0265/) suggests this for sorting a dictionary by values.

```
import operator
sorted(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

If you want descending order, do this

```
sorted(d.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

no lambda method

```
# sort dictionary by value
d = {'a1': 'fsdfds', 'g5': 'aa3432ff', 'ca':'zz23432'}
def getkeybyvalue(d,i):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v == i:
            return (k)

sortvaluelist = sorted(d.values())
sortresult ={}
for i1 in sortvaluelist:   
    key = getkeybyvalue(d,i1)
    sortresult[key] = i1
print ('=====sort by value=====')
print (sortresult)
print ('=======================')
```