# Sort Python List

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list, and it is currently sorted by key(A,B,C). The value is a number count of how many times the key appears in a file. The code gives results like this:

```
14 A
157 B
17 C
...
```

I need to reverse this order around. I want to sort by the value instead of key so it reads like this:

```
14 A
17 C
157 B
```

I have read and tried all the documentation I could find on here and Google. I don't think it should be too complex, but I am overthinking something.

Is there a simple solution to read the order by number value? Also every time I try to sort by value, it says 'int or str is not callable'. I don't understand what this means.

Some of my code is below:

```
lst = list()
for key, val in counts.items():
    lst.append((key, val))
lst.sort()    

for key, val in lst:
   print val, key
```

Comment: Look at the list method `sort` and the parameter `key`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16772088/489590

Comment: Thanks Brian. I tried this too. I was having issues with sorted() versus sort() too.

Comment: Does it make a difference if I'm using list or tuple or dictionary for this concept? Is one method preferred over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.sort` accept optional `key` parameter.

```
>>> counts = {
...     'A': 14,
...     'B': 157,
...     'C': 17,
... }
>>>
>>> lst = counts.items()
>>> lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]) # x[1] => count
>>> for key, val in lst:
...     print val, key
...
14 A
17 C
157 B
```

According to [Mutable Sequence Types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#mutable-sequence-types):

> The `sort()` method takes optional arguments for controlling the comparisons.
>
> ...
>
> `key` specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a
>   comparison key from each list element: key=str.lower. The default
>   value is None.

Comment: Thank you falsetru, this solution also works. Can you explain the line and syntax for lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])? How does this read? Is the [1] representing the value's position in the list?

Comment: @MariaGosur, `lambda` is a kind of anonymous function. `lambda x: x[1]` is a function that return the 2nd item of the passed parameter. `x` here is each item of the list.

Comment: ah okay. I get it in brief overview. I have to spend more time studying the lambda in practice, though I've vaguely used it. Makes sense though in essence. Thank you for explaining it. This helps a lot.

Comment: I'm still getting used to Stackoverflow. I had to start a new account and lost all my rep points. It's giving me a hard time accepting the answers, but I like your answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

The `key` argument to `sort()` allows you to specify the sorting key.

You could use:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda (k,v):v)
```

or, equivalently,

```
lst.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help NPE. I really appreciate it. The first line suggestion worked well. However, I don't know that I fully grasp what that line is reading. Can you explain the syntax of the lambda and :v being used?

Answer (score 0):

This works, assuming

```
import operator
for key, val in counts.items():
  lst.append((key, val))
# lst should be like this :
# lst = [('A',14), ('B',157), ('C',17), ('D',12), ('E',189)]
sorted_lst = sorted(set(lst), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print sorted_lst
```

Comment: Thank you fjammes. I have not dove too deep into the python imports, but I will look further into this. I appreciate and value everyone's help!