# Python: How to sort a dictionary of X and Y coordinates by ascending X coordinate value?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have the following dictionary that I would like to sort based on their X coordinate in ascending fashion so that I can identify the "beacon" by the color arrangement (RGB in different orders). I keep trying to sort it like a list but that's not working out too well.  Thanks in advance :)

```
Beacon2 = {
    'r': [998.9282836914062, 367.3825378417969],
    'b': [985.82373046875, 339.2225646972656], 
    'g': [969.539794921875, 369.2041931152344]
}
```

For this specific dictionary the expected result is

```
sortedBeacon = {
    'g': [969.539794921875, 369.2041931152344], 
    'b': [985.82373046875, 339.2225646972656],
    'r': [998.9282836914062, 367.3825378417969]
}
```

Comment: Dictionaries aren't sorted

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: For this specific dictionary the expected result is sortedBeacon = {'g': [969.539794921875, 369.2041931152344], 'b': [985.82373046875, 
339.2225646972656], 'r': [998.9282836914062, 367.3825378417969]}

Comment: Dictionaries being sorted is an implementation detail, and should not be relied on. You should use an `OrderedDict` instead, which will let you do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

Beacon2 = {'r': [998.9282836914062, 367.3825378417969], 'b':
[985.82373046875, 339.2225646972656], 'g': [969.539794921875, 369.2041931152344]}

sorted_beacons = sorted(Beacon2.items(), key = lambda x: x[1][0])

>>> print(OrderedDict(sorted_beacons))
OrderedDict([('g', [969.539794921875, 369.2041931152344]), ('b', [985.82373046875, 339.2225646972656]), ('r', [998.9282836914062, 367.3825378417969])])
```

Where you first sort the list of tuples from `Beacon2.items()`, with a sorting key applied on the X coordinate located at `[1][0]` of each tuple.

Note that you need to wrap an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to your result to preserve order of the dictionary.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks :)

Comment: @Kara But this is descending order within the list. Was that expected?

Comment: The first value within the items are ascending. The list themselves are descending

Comment: @cricket_007 I wanted the values the way they are here, ascending by X value maintaining corresponding keys

Answer (score 3):

Note that dictionaries in general are not sortable. You can generate the internals sorted however without any lambdas by using `itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
```

If you really want to maintain order, wrap the above in an `OrderedDict`

Answer (score 1):

The method sort() in Python is normally used on lists and tuples whereas sorted() is better for data structures like dictionaries.

In this case, using a simple lambda function can help you get what you want.

```
print(sorted(Beacon2.values(), key = lambda x: (x[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the values, use this:

```
sorted(data.values())
```

If you want the keys associated with the sorted values, use this:

```
sorted(data, key=data.get)
```

Both key and values:

```
sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Courtesy of: [sort dict by value python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772071/sort-dict-by-value-python)

Comment: `sorted(data.values())` will sort the lists against each other , not the values within them