# How to access entries of a list using a numpy array without using a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Given a list `L = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. What's the best way to access/extract elements where their indices are given by a numpy array? Let `nArr=np.array([0,-1,2,6])`.

The resulting output should be another list `P = [0,9,2,6]`.

It is clear that when the elements are uniform in shape, we can simply cast it into another numpy array, but what if it isn't? For example, `M = [np.random.rand(5,5), np.random.rand(1)]`.

Comment: `[L[i] for i in nArr]`?

Comment: I should have mentioned, without using a for loop.

Comment: @RakshitKothari um, why can't you use a for-loop?

Comment: You're not going to get anything better than a list comprehension.

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, because elements can have different sizes.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Just wondering if I can do this with logical indexing.

Comment: Lists don't support that.

Comment: What do you mean "logical indexing"? It is not very clear what you are looking for. In any event, if you are trying to index a list like a numpy array, you can't.

Comment: @user2357112 So that's a definitive no on logical indexing

Comment: You can cast any list to a numpy array of dtype `object`. And on that you can do logical indexing etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stock Python has a convenience class, `itemgetter`:

```
In [27]: from operator import itemgetter
In [28]: L = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
In [29]: nArr=np.array([0,-1,2,6])
In [30]: itemgetter(*nArr)
Out[30]: operator.itemgetter(0, -1, 2, 6)
In [31]: itemgetter(*nArr)(L)
Out[31]: (0, 9, 2, 6)
```

Internally it does something equivalent to the list comprehension:

```
In [33]: [L[x] for x in nArr]
Out[33]: [0, 9, 2, 6]
```

So it isn't a fast operation like the array indexing (look at its code).  It may be most useful as a way of doing `sort` or other operations where you'd like to define a `key` function that fetches multiple values.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47585659/901925

Make a random nested list:

```
In [54]: arr = np.random.randint(0,10,(4,4))
In [55]: L = arr.tolist()
In [56]: L
Out[56]: [[9, 5, 8, 4], [1, 5, 5, 8], [8, 0, 5, 8], [1, 4, 5, 1]]
```

lexical sort by 'column':

```
In [57]: sorted(L)
Out[57]: [[1, 4, 5, 1], [1, 5, 5, 8], [8, 0, 5, 8], [9, 5, 8, 4]]
```

lexical sort by 'columns' 2 and 1 (in that order):

```
In [59]: sorted(L, key=itemgetter(2,1))
Out[59]: [[8, 0, 5, 8], [1, 4, 5, 1], [1, 5, 5, 8], [9, 5, 8, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the comments: lists do not support indexing by an array, like `L[nArr]` where nArr is an array of indexes. One normally uses list comprehension, `[L[i] for i in nArr]`. But if you want to, you can cast the list to a NumPy array of *objects*, which can then be indexed and sliced as any other NumPy array:

```
np.array(L, dtype=object)[nArr]
```

If you want a list returned, you can do:

```
np.array(L, dtype=object)[nArr].tolist()
```

But that's not nearly as pythonic as list comprehension, requires more memory, and very likely doesn't improve the speed.

Comment: I think Crazy Ivan meant `np.array(L, dtype=object)[nArr]`. Or this will work as well `np.array(L)[nArr]`