# ‘List’ object not callable for dict string: integer

Tags: python

I’m encountering this issue where I have a dict: map-x-to-y = {} and fill it with values such as map-x-to-y[some-string] = counter.

But afterwards, If i try to call sorted I keep on getting ‘list’ object not callable error.

I tried with OrderedDict and with sorted and none of this works.
Also, I checked the type of map-x-to-y and it is ‘dict’.

My goal is to sort map-x-to-y in a descending order by value.

Comment: can you share the actual version of the code you have?

Comment: @timgeb just an example

Comment: Your examples should be runnable, i.e. [MCVE].

Comment: `sorted` returns a list. It won't return a `dict`. Maybe you want a list of `tuple`s?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sort dict by value python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772071/sort-dict-by-value-python)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1):

Some key points

1. `sorted` is for `list` not `dict`. Unless you know how to represent your dict as a list. Best answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16772088/806802). My method is below
2. You need to somehow represent your dict as a list
3. you also need to swap keys for values and values for keys
4. By value I presume you want your returned list to be sorted by descending order of the value in the map

Try this

```
In [12]: humans
Out[12]: {'Ashley': 33, 'Danny': 33, 'Jackie': 12, 'Jenny': 22}

In [13]: sorted([ (y,x) for x,y in humans.items()])[::-1]
Out[13]: [(33, 'Danny'), (33, 'Ashley'), (22, 'Jenny'), (12, 'Jackie')]
```

#### Explanation

- use `items` to convert your dict to a list of tuples
- use list comprehension to switch the pairs around
- sort the returned list
- reverse it