# How can I sort a dictionary by value as-is (sort in a dict format) in python?

Tags: python

I try to sort a dictionary by value using

`sort = sorted(the_dict.items(), key = lambda x : x[1])`

but this returns a list of tuples.

How can I return a dict that has the keys sorted in descending value order?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 3 version

Comment: 3.what?  Since 3.6 you can do something like `x = dict(sorted(the_dict.items(), key = lambda x : x[1]))`

Comment: check this [link](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/09/how-to-sort-python-dictionary-by-keys/)

Comment: It does not really sort by the value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sort dict by value python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772071/sort-dict-by-value-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close, you need a `dict()` constructor to make it a dictionary, note that `operator.itemgetter(1)` could replace `lambda`

```
d = {'vash': 1, 'the': 5, 'stampede': 12}
new_d = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)) 
# {'stampede': 12, 'the': 5, 'vash': 1}
```

Comment: Awesome! Somehow I missed this change in the 3.7 release notes.

Comment: @JoelCornett no prob like I said you were right there ha