# Is there a dictionary module in Python with ordering built-in?

Tags: python

I know that there is an OrderedDict class but what I actually want is sort of a mix between dict and PriorityQueue.

So if iterate over the dict, I'd like for the items to be ordered by value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python dictionary values sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046049/python-dictionary-values-sorting)

Comment: Please describe exactly what features you are looking for, and why `OrderedDict` does not meet your needs.

Comment: @ron: yes, you can sort but is there a way to avoid the separate sort like OrderedDict?

Comment: @Matt: OrderedDict is only ordered by insert. What I have explicitly asked for is ordered by value

Comment: What's wrong with `sorted()`?

Comment: it will add an extra function call that's all. If there's nothing else, then I guess that has to be it.

Comment: @user55570: Okay, now I think I see what you want.  You're asking if there's a data structure that maintains the sort order so that iterating is only an O(n) operation?  (Not O(nlogn) like sorted.)

Answer (score 1):

You can sort a dictionary based on value like so...

```
my_dict = {...}
for key in sorted(my_dict, key=lambda x: my_dict[x]):
    print (key + " " + my_dict[key])
```

Keep in mind that the dictionary will not be sorted in place, you just get a sorted representation of the dictionary.

Also note that you can define the basis on which to sort the values via the lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = { ... }
print sorted(d, key=lambda x: d[x])
```

---

Edit: You've indicated in a comment that you don't care about performance; rather you prefer that the client code (code that uses the dict) to be as clean and simple as possible.  Here's an approach you might try:

```
# hide the "sorted" business in a class
class ValueSortedDict(dict):
    def sorted_by_value(self):
        return sorted(self, key=lambda x: self[x])

# client code just calls sorted_by_value
vsd = ValueSortedDict({ ... })
print vsd.sorted_by_value()
```

(FTR, If it were me I wouldn't use this approach; I'd go with just calling `sorted` as needed.)

Comment: Is there nothing else that avoids having to sort?

Comment: Hmm.  Well, would you be willing to accept worse performance during inserts?  Dict insertions are (amortized) O(1), and sorting would be O(nlogn).  If you're doing many, many more reads than inserts, then I can see a case for optimizing the reads at the expense of inserts.  But just checking that that's what you want.

Comment: Have you considered whether a [heap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) is appropriate for your needs?

Comment: i am not too concerned about performance. I'd like the ability to do both indexed access and iteration on sorted data, with as simple looking code as possible.

Comment: If you don't care about performance but simply want clean client code, perhaps you could wrap `dict` in your own class and "hide" the `sorted` call in a method there.  I'll edit my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: btw, the lambda should be lambda x:x

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is impossible. Here is a simple sketch proof. Lets say a "DictionQueue" existed. Because it's like a python dictionary, it has O(1) insertion, retrieval and deletion of key, value pairs. Because it's like a Priority Queue, it allows you to iterate over the values in sorted order. If I have N values, I can insert them into the "DictionQueue" and iterate over them as a method of sorting those values. The insertion/iteration for N items will be order O(N), but we know that the fastest possible comparison sort is O(N*log(N)). Therefore a "DictionQueue" cannot exist.

There might still be a data structure that's better for your purposes than a dictionary, but you'll need to define where you're willing to compromise. For example do you need retrieval by key or only insertion and iteration?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think the OP wants O(N) performance for sort? I really don't get that from the question. Sounds to me like a Python equivalent of Java's `TreeMap` would suit the OP.

Comment: @jpmc26 OP is asking for "a mix between dict and PriorityQueue." A data structure that has _all_ the features of both would have an _implied_ ability to do an O(N) sort. Therefore such a data structure cannot exist. A `TreeMap` would have all the features of a python `Mapping` (`Mapping` is an abstract super class of `dict`) and a Priority Queue but would not have all the features of a `dict`. Maybe you're right, maybe that's all the OP needs but we can't be sure without more info.

Comment: The OP is clearly not looking for an implementation with *all* those features. They explicitly lay out what features are important to them. The important features are ordered iteration (explicitly mentioned) and key based look up (implied by the request for a dictionary like structure). There's no mention of performance anywhere, never mind O(N), and the OP clarifies later in comments that performance in unimportant to them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a third party implementation? Here's one: [`SortedDict`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html), part of the [`sortedcontainers`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sortedcontainers) package.